# How to call a user input in a method in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make this send the user input number to the function but I do not know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
puts "\n Amount with decimals:\n "
STDOUT.flush
numb = gets

puts "\n Multiplier:\n "
STDOUT.flush
mult = gets

stoque(0.01, numb, 0.5, mult, 1)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what going on? What's happening and what do you expect to be happening? That code does in fact get the user input and send it to the method

Comment: If you need a number, maybe `mult.to_f`?

Comment: Note that `STDOUT.flush` can usually be omitted. Ruby auto-flushes when writing to a terminal device (tty).

Comment: "I do not know what I am doing wrong" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

If you need floats, you need to convert the inputs to them:

```
numb = gets.to_f
...
mult = gets.to_f
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want Ruby to raise an exception for invalid (i.e. non-decimal) input, you can also use:

```
numb = Float(gets)
```

Some examples:<sup>1</sup>

```
gets    | gets.to_f  | Float(gets)
--------+------------+--------------
'1'     | 1.0        | 1.0
'.5'    | 0.5        | 0.5
'1.2.3' | 1.2        | ArgumentError
''      | 0.0        | ArgumentError
'foo'   | 0.0        | ArgumentError
```

Because of the exception, you probably want to wrap it in a `begin-rescue` block, something like:

```
puts 'Amount with decimals:'
begin
  numb = Float(gets)
rescue ArgumentError
  puts 'Invalid amount'
  retry
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> note that `gets` includes the newline character `"\n"` if the input is entered with <kbd>return</kbd>. I've omitted it because trailing newlines are ignored by both, `to_f` and `Float()`.